# How to add pages to navigation on Pelican?

Tags: python, pelican

I know this may not be a very smart question, but it really bother me for a while.

I am using `Pelican` for site generating, with theme `SoMA/SoMA2`. I am adding a folder under content and some pages inside. This should appear on the navigation according to the [Tutorial](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.4.0/content.html?highlight=navigation#pages), but didn't.

I tried with default theme (in quickstart) and it works. Does it mean `SoMA/SoMA2` don't support personalized navigation? Any ways I can do with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct: the SoMA/SoMA2 themes do not currently add pages to the navigation menu. You can see this by comparing the [notmyidea base template](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/themes/notmyidea/templates/base.html) with the [SoMA base template](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/blob/master/SoMA/templates/base.html). The relevant code is:

```
            {% if DISPLAY_PAGES_ON_MENU -%}
            {% for pg in PAGES %}
                <li{% if pg == page %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ pg.url }}">{{ pg.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
```

I can't guarantee that will be entirely sufficient, of course, since I haven't fully examined how SoMA implements its navigation, CSS, et cetera. But perhaps this might point you in the right direction.